# Create a Loading Screen without a specific time

Tags: android, screen, loading

Here is my problem, when I open an activity, it start to process an image using a native method (jni) and i dont want a black screen, i want to show a message of wait or a loading wheel.

I cant determite how long gonna take the image processing.

Comment: use an indeterminate `ProgressDialog`

Comment: What have tried already?

Comment: I tried both, but the problem it is that i cant call native method inside on a thread. How i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Did this and worked for me:

```
final ProgressDialog progress;
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(PlayStaff.this, "Loading",
                    "Processing Image", true);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do the thing that takes a long time
                processImageNativeMethodJNI();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progress.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handler here also.

```
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);               
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

You can add any other animation, message and all in your Spalshscreen.java file and it's Layout file.